# FindGameObjectsWithTag does not work after build

Tags: unity-game-engine, onmousedown

Script not working in build - ok in editor.

It looks like this:

```
public GameObject [] fMassiv;
```

These are the tags I am looking for:

`f_line14 (UnityEngine.GameObject)` or `f_line15 (UnityEngine.GameObject)` or `f_line16 (UnityEngine.GameObject)` etc.

```
void OnMouseDown () 
{
    string f_string = "f_line" + searchable number + "(UnityEngine.GameObject)";

    fMassiv = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag (f_string); // and here in the build everything shuts up (((
}
```

The postscript: `(UnityEngine.GameObject)`, is made by you itself. objects are cloned from the prefab.

But here that is curious.
If I bring `f_string` to the console, I’ll see: `f_line16 (UnityEngine.GameObject)`,
and if in `TextBox`, then only: `f_line16`.

I tried to drive into the array and so:

```
fMassiv = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("f_line" + number);
```

or

```
fMassiv = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("f_line" + number + "(UnityEngine.GameObject)";
```

does not work.

Once again: in Unity, everything works great.

sorry for my English

Comment: `"f_line" + searchable number + "(UnityEngine.GameObject)";` is this a typo or do you really have a space in the variable name?

Answer (score 2):

Just a detail I noticed:

In your tag-descriptions e.g. f_line14 (UnityEngine.GameObject) (copied from above) there is a "space" between the f_lineXX and (UnityEngine.GameObject).

While this line of code:

```
string f_string = "f_line" + number + "(UnityEngine.GameObject)";
```

does not generate the same format (space is missing).

Are you manually creating your tags? Or are they procedurally created (through code)? Generally I cannot think of any reason that this would work in the editor but not in the build.

Some more info might help. Form example: are your gameobjects just scene objects? Or are they instantiated prefabs?